# how to upsert data in mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

I need to update data in MySQL if present in the table, or it should insert data to that table.I have given a query which I tried.

// inside table only id is unique which is autoincrement

```
  REPLACE INTO books (user_id,books_name,books_value,books_id)\ Values ('"+event.user_id+"','"+event.books+"','"+event.books+"','"+event.books+"') where books_id like "12"
```

Comment: Is there anything not working with the given query?

Comment: if data present in the table I need to update  or a new record should be inserted

Comment: The [`REPLACE` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) doesn't have a `WHERE` clause (what for?). `id` should be together with the rest of the columns. However, I suggest you read about the statement to ensure it does what you think it does.

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve the problem? Using my favorite search engine, I can find tons of tutorials that could help

Comment: Your question is not complete:  update *what* values?  how is a duplicate defined?

Comment: I see virtually no use for `REPLACE`; IODKU seems to replace all uses of it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description I think you want to use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, since replace into always inserts.
And, assuming that the books_id is the key column, it'd look something like this

```
INSERT INTO books (user_id, books_name, books_value, books_id)
VALUES ('user id','bookname','book value', '12')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
 user_id = VALUES.user_id,
 books_name = VALUES.books_name,
 books_value = VALUES.books_value
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html